# Scala Scoverage - How to generate HTML report?

Tags: scala, testing, report, scoverage

By default if you configure scoverage plugin into maven project, it generates an XML report.

**However, is there any way how to specify that the generated report should be HTML ?**

Thanks!
V.

Comment: HTML report is generated in `target/site/scoverage` directory.

Comment: @GrzegorzSlowikowski I do not have any site directory.

Comment: Please, open an issue in plugin repo and attach Maven execution log. I will check it.

Comment: This issue seems resolved. the HTML report is generated in `target/site/scoverage` directory.